# Hadoop dependences error when I tried to install pxf-service

Tags: hawq

I build Apache Hawq from source. When I tried install pxf-service, the error below occurs:

```
[root@host-172-16-0-108 hawqadmin]# rpm -ivh pxf-service-3.0.0-22126.noarch.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
        hadoop >= 2.7.1 is needed by pxf-service-0:3.0.0-22126.noarch
        hadoop-hdfs >= 2.7.1 is needed by pxf-service-0:3.0.0-22126.noarch
```

I've already installed hadoop-2.7.2. Any advice?

Comment: This is caused by rpm dependencies. Just do `rpm -qa | grep hadoop` and see the output. If you won't see hadoop >= 2.7.1 or hadoop-hdfs >= 2.7.1 this is the source of your problem

Comment: I installed hadoop with tar-ball not rpm, so when I execute _rpm -qa | grep hadoop_ ,it give nothing. Do I have to install hadoop with rpm tar-ball?

Comment: It means that you have taken official HDB 2.0 build from Pivotal and trying to install it on tarballed Apache Hadoop. This is not the right thing to do. Official build has official installation guide (http://hdb.docs.pivotal.io/hdb20/releasenotes/HAWQ20ReleaseNotes.html) that outlines requirements for the installation, and requirement is HDP, which provides the RPMs listed above

Comment: However, if you want to play with Apache HAWQ, you are free to build it by yourself with desired version of Apache Hadoop. When you build it, you won't pack it into RPMs with Hadoop version requirements and would be able to use it the way you like

Comment: I did't use HDB2.0. I build it from Apache HAWQ following the official build instruction. How can I build it so that the pxf can work with the hadoop I installed? Thanks.

Comment: IMO you should try building it in tar instead of RPM (https://github.com/apache/incubator-hawq/blob/01a27b7406d31a7ab5aa307b360f01c466165596/pxf/Makefile#L52). It has a number of dependencies (this is the one you hit - https://github.com/apache/incubator-hawq/blob/fd9c36861506ac94255a34c6a85307bf87ae0f72/pxf/build.gradle#L198), so it won't be easy to make a custom build. After all, Apache HAWQ is still in early days. You can create an issue on this topic in official JIRA (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HAWQ), this should be fixed

Comment: Thanks ! I read the first two link, I have no clue how to do it. It seems only to support phd&hdp. hit me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue with the prebuilt packages downloaded from pivotal.io pages. This is not an issue related to the build from the sources. I found that both pxf-service-0:3.0.0-22126.noarch and apache-tomcat-0:7.0.62-.noarch packages use the same directory /opt/pivotal with different owner - Tomcat with tomcat:tomcat and PFX with root:root. There is some discussion in Jira. I workarounded that issue by installing Apache Tomcat using

yum install apache-tomcat ;
rpm -ivh /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/HDB/packages/pxf-service-3.0.0-22126.noarch.rpm --nodeps --replacefiles

You should change ownership and permissions on /opt/pivotal to work with apache-tomcat package as well.

PFX correctly installs and runs on Hortonworks HDP 2.4.2.0-258 cluster.

Comment: As far as I know, the conflicts between pxf-service and tomcat have been fixed in the newest source of Apache Hawq. Did you use Apache Hadoop or HDP?

Comment: I used HDP 2.4.2. The conflict is in one shared folder as mentioned above. Since it works, I did not have any reason to play with further recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you built this RPM from open source? the RPM package build# 22126 is an internal build# from Pivotal Commercial product.

Comment: I checked out incubator-hawq from github, and I built pxf RPM packages by execute command _./gradlew clean buildRpm_ in _incubator-hawq/pxf_ directory. When I tried to install pxf service ,the dependencies error I mentioned above occured . In _incubator-hawq/pxf/Makefile_ file, I noticed `@echo "  -  -  HD=<phd|hdp> - set classpath to match hadoop distribution. default phd"`, does this mean pxf only support phd&hdp? If not ,how can I build the right pxf packages compatible with Apache Hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `--nodeps` to the RPM installation, however, this is not the "correct" way, from either HDB's or RPM's perspective, to install software. Either build and install everything from source or use RPM tarballs, which handle dependency management for you.

`# rpm -ivh pxf-service-3.0.0-22126.noarch.rpm --nodeps`

Comment: When I tried your way, the following error comes up:

```[hawqadmin@host-172-16-0-108 ~]$ sudo rpm -i pxf-service-3.0.0-22126.noarch.rpm --nodeps
        file /opt/pivotal from install of pxf-service-0:3.0.0-22126.noarch conflicts with file from package apache-tomcat-0:7.0.62-.noarch```

Comment: Not sure why apache-tomcat is installing files in ```/opt/pivotal``` but you can also try adding the ```--replacefiles``` option.